# Ubuntu 16.05 Flash Upgrade From Version11.2.202.635 to 23.0.0.162

Tags: flash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

When I try to upgrade to the latest version of Flash I am receiving the error message

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't understand how to resolve this.

I am trying to make the upgrade through [Adobe Flash Player Download](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).  I've been selecting the option "APT For Ubuntu 10.04+"

I don't know what other information I need to provide to resolve this.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find and remove the pidgin-developers PPA from /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list